# Django rendered page incorrect:missing content

Tags: python, django

When I debug django project on localhost,**sometimes** the rendered html is incorrect.

For example:the correct is this:

```
<a href="/tag/Vim/">Vim</a>
.......
</p>
```

and it just become to this:

```
<a href="/ta
</p>
```

Too many content is missed.When I refresh the page,It will be OK. This happens also in **Django admin**.

(I'm using PostgreSQL now,this also happens with sqllite3)

What's the most probably reason,is this a common problem?

---

update:

template:https://gist.github.com/bebound/6231762

correct:https://gist.github.com/bebound/6231841

incorrect:https://gist.github.com/bebound/6231859

Comment: can you show the full template and how you're rendering it please? not sure, but that seems like a weird regex issue (considering how it's stripped). Also, is that `</p>` open somewhere else?

Comment: I think this isn't a template error, it renders correctly most of the time. The same input can't return the same output,this confused me..".......</p>" just show many content is missed,like someone delete it. @SamueleMattiuzzo

Comment: Again, can we see the template and the view you're using? And maybe know something more about your system etc etc? Sounds like you're trying to refresh the page before it actually loaded (since you say that after a second refresh, you see everything as you'd expect)

Comment: I'm using win7 64bit,py3.3 32bit with latest django.I'm sure the page is full loaded, if I refresh the correct page,it can become to the incorrect,like the django sometimes returns an incomplete respond.

Comment: hum, can I then see your `urls.py` file and your views and models? don't be shy :)

Comment: All of the files: https://github.com/bebound/django-blog/ @SamueleMattiuzzo